# X11: Window properties not working for gtk-windows

Tags: properties, gtk, x11

in a program I need to figure out the `WM_CLASS` property of the window currently in focus. This works fine using `XGetInputFocus()` and `XGetClassHint()` as long as the focused window is not a gtk application.

I wrote the following minimal example program `wmclass.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    Window win;
    Display *d;
    XClassHint *clh;

    int rev;
    int status;

    clh = XAllocClassHint();
    d = XOpenDisplay(0);

    for(;;) {
        XGetInputFocus(d, &win, &rev);
        status = XGetClassHint(d,win,clh);
        if (status) 
            printf("name: %s, class: %s\n", clh->res_name,clh->res_class);
        else 
            printf("failed\n");
        sleep(1);
    }

    XFree(clh);
}
```

This program prints:

> name: xterm, class: XTerm
>   name: xterm, class: XTerm
>   failed
>   failed
>   failed
>   name: xterm, class: XTerm
>   name: xterm, class: XTerm
>   name: okular, class: Okular
>   name: okular, class: Okular
>   failed
>   failed
>   name: xterm, class: XTerm
>   name: xterm, class: XTerm
>   name: xterm, class: XTerm

`failed` comes if a gtk app is focused. I tested emacs, gimp, chromium and ardour.

Why is that? How do I get `WM_CLASS` of gtk-windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus is not necessarily set to a top-level window. In particular, Gtk tends to set it to a child of such window.

You need to walk the window tree up.